# How to run this python function for each file in my directory?

Tags: python, function

I have a function that should clean up csv files included on my list:

```
fileListLocalDaily = (glob.glob("/path/to/my/directory/*.csv")
for y in fileListLocalDaily:
    data = y
    def prepare_file(y):
        data = y
        lines = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        new_lines = lines.replace('something', '', regex=True)
        f = StringIO(data)
        # extract date
        date = next(f)
        date = date.split('_')[1]
        date = os.path.splitext(date)[0]
        new_lines.insert(2,'date',date)
        new_lines.drop(new_lines.columns[0:2], axis=1, inplace=True)
        new_lines.drop(new_lines.columns[6], axis=1, inplace=True)
        new_lines=new_lines.sort_values(by=['Something'], ascending=False) 
        new_lines.to_csv('/path/to/my/output/'+date+'.csv', index = False)
        complete = prepare_file(data)
runFunction = prepare_file(y)
```

It seems that the above function saved only one file and kept overwriting it over and over in an endless loop. Could someone help me understand how could I run this function to all csv files in my directory one after one? thanks

Comment: Do all your files have the same `date`, which would cause the output file to be the same? Have you considered using the name of the input file to determine what to name the output file, since you _know_ that all the input files have distinct names?

Comment: Looks like an indentation error.  In its current structure, `runFunction = prepare_file(y)` should it inside the `for` loop.  Also, move the function itself outside the loop.

Comment: Hi Green Cloak Guy, all my filenames are unique and have different dates at the end of the file name that looks something like _00-00-0000.csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code you’ve provided, your loop isn’t actually doing anything. You’re defining the function over and over again, but you don’t call it in the loop because your indentation for the last line is outside of the loop. Your function also called itself at the end, so it was entering an infinite loop. You should define the function once and then call it inside of the loop:

```py
def prepare_file(data):
    lines = pd.read_csv(data, sep=",", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    new_lines = lines.replace('something', '', regex=True)
    f = StringIO(data)
    # extract date
    date = next(f)
    date = date.split('_')[1]
    date = os.path.splitext(date)[0]
    new_lines.insert(2,'date',date)
    new_lines.drop(new_lines.columns[0:2], axis=1, inplace=True)
    new_lines.drop(new_lines.columns[6], axis=1, inplace=True)
    new_lines=new_lines.sort_values(by=['Something'], ascending=False) 
    new_lines.to_csv('/path/to/my/output/'+date+'.csv', index = False)

fileListLocalDaily = (glob.glob("/path/to/my/directory/*.csv")
for data in fileListLocalDaily:
    prepare_file(data)
```

`prepare_file` doesn’t return anything, so the assignment operator was just assigning `None` there, so I removed the assignment. I also renamed `y` directly to `data` in both the loop and the function.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use os.walk to get all files recursively

```
import os
top = '/path/to/my/directory'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top):
for name in files:
    if os.path.splitext(name) == ".csv":
        # do stuff with name here
        # use os.path.join(root, name) for the full file path
```

Comment: This would be better placed as a comment, as it does not answer the question; but is a critique of the iteration method.  Additionally, OP uses `glob` which returns the full file path, and will not need to join the parts, as `walk` requires.  (I’m a `walk` to `glob` convertee ... so I understand where you’re coming from).